# how to find the imaginary roots of fourth degree cannot be simplified?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

How to find all roots of the following:

$$x^4 + 4 = 0$$
I know all roots will be imaginary.
I tried to find a solution on the internet but could not find any.

Comment: Hint: Set $x= re^{i \theta}$

Comment: They are the four [fourth-roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root#nth_roots) of $-4$.  You might see such a list of roots written via [De Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula#Roots_of_complex_numbers).

Comment: Also, as a nitpick., each of these roots will be *complex*, not purely imaginary.  A number like $2+3i$ is neither real nor imaginary, it is a combination of the two.

Answer (score 1):

The roots are $4^{1/4}\omega$ where $\omega$ is a fourth root of $-1$, namely $4^{1/4}e^{i(2k-1)\pi/4}, k=0,1,2,3$.

Answer (score 0):

From the Sophie Germain identity, we have $x^4+4 = (x^2+2x+2)(x^2-2x+2)$, the roots of the quadratic polynomials are $-1+i,-1-i,1+i,1-i$.